# AWS Amplify Static site not routing as expected. Needs a final urls need a final '/'

Tags: aws-amplify

Serving a site from AWS Amplify I noted a problem that all my category pages just looked like the home page.  I thought this may be a template issue or something but I downloaded the artifacts and confirmed that the pages were being formed as they should have.

I narrowed down the problem to routing.

For example `http://example.com/some-uri` returns a page, that is actually my homepage not a 404 and not a redirect to my homepage.  However `http://example.com/some-uri/` routes to the correct resource, for example `/some-uri/index.html`.

This behaviour kind of puts me off using pretty permalinks as my development server does not require the trailing /.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this by serving my page from `/some-uri.html` not `/some-uri/index.html` and will post a more comprehensive answer if I work out how it all works.

Comment: This works for now! I had an extension-less file Amplify refused to serve without a redirection. By adding the ".html" extension, the file is now accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Amplify has a pretty advanced "rewrites and redirects" and configuration panel and a section in the documentation on establishing desired routing.

The following section suggests that the expected behaviour, of routing from `/some-uri` to `/some-uri/index.html` should be automatic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#trailing-slashes-and-clean-urls

I found this to be the case, but only when I removed the rule that was present at time of creation redirecting all 404 back to my homepage.